How to use play framework macros to parse and process json?
I am trying to convert json from one structure to another. In the process I would like to add a prefix to one of the string fields (if it exists). I need to use the play framework.
How would I add-to/process json fields as they are parsed using macros?
case class Book(title: Option[String], author: Option[String], published: Option[Long], info: JsObject)
object Book {
  implicit val bookImplicitReads = Json.reads[Book]
  implicit val bookImplicitWrites = Json.writes[Book]
}

def bookConvertor(inputObject: JsObject) = {
  Try {
    val title = (inputObject \ "title").asOpt[String]
    val author = (inputObject \ "author").asOpt[String]
    val published = (inputObject \ "metadata" \ "published").asOpt[Long]

    Book(title, author, published)
  } match {
    case Success(book) =>
      Json.toJsObject(book)
  }
}

How would I make the above prepend the title and author strings with "Title:" and "Author" respectively?

Play JSON doesn't have to be macro-based...

Look at the transform method on the Writes and preprocess method on the Reads for how to adapt those to work with a different JSON structure.
